# Handling AttributeError when adding a new variable in class

Tags: python, class, exception, nameerror

I'm working on a class, on a Discord Bot.

```
import pickle

class My_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 0
    def add_function(self, amount):
        self.var1 += amount

def save(c):
    # save class in file
    with open("my_pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(c, f)

def load():
    # load class from file
    with open("my_pickle", "rb") as f:
        c = pickle.load(f)
    return c

def init_save():
    # make class if not exists
    Myclass = My_class()
    save(Myclass)

def function():
    Myclass = load()
    Myclass.add_function(50)
    save(Myclass)
    print(Myclass.var1)

try:
    function()
except FileNotFoundError:
    init_save()
    function()
```

I store a class in a pickle file, and I want to update the class, adding a new variable on it.

so I changed My_class as below:

```
class My_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 0
        self.new_var = 0
    def add_function(self, amount):
        self.var1 += amount
        self.new_var += amount
```

since I saved old My_class in my_pickle, AttributeError rises when I run the code. ('My_class' object has no attribute 'new_var')
so I have to edit code like below,

```
class My_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 0
        self.new_var = 0
    def add_function(self, amount):
        self.var1 += amount
        try:
            self.new_var += amount
        except AttributeError:
            self.new_var = 0
```

Is there a way to simple this? or do I have to handle this error every time I update class? thanks for your help.

Comment: This should be an `AttributeError` in your example, actually.

Comment: Given that you set it in `__init__`, why would it suddenly disappear?

Comment: "If I made a Class before adding new variable, I have to handle Error like above.": No you don't

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added a new variable after assigning a class in a variable.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial and play around for a bit to understand what you're doing first

Comment: Foo()._bar() keep no reference of the object... how you retrieve the attribute values? your class is not buged just your call

Comment: @MadPhysicist I meant, in a online project, I have already assigned a class, and I want to add a new variable on this class.

Comment: @hoony. My statement still holds

Comment: You will need to explain what you think you're doing and why you think you need to do it. There's some fundamental misunderstanding there, but we can't diagnose that based on your sparse explanation is misdirected questions.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry for weak description, I added some. thanks!

Comment: Still makes no sense. For what you're describing to happen, you'd need to somehow be able to partially replace a class in a running program on the fly. Which… just… doesn't happen all that easily…

Comment: @hoony "if I run the add_function on class, it raises NameError since Myclass has no variable called 'new_var'" is not true. You need to make a [mcve] that shows how you get the error, and an error with complete traceback. You're either making stuff up or not reading error messages. Either way, I need more information to help you

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am so sorry about wasting your time, again, I rewrote question. thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: I think I understand what's going on. If you want to change your class format, you need to add that information to the loader, not the class. I've voted to reopen

Comment: Is adding setattr to a class makes sense?